# Using Robolectric without Multidexing?

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric, dex, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am working on an Android application and I want to use Robolectric for testing.

The main problem I have is, whenever I include Robolectric (and a few other testing libraries) to my gradle.build file, I get Dex errors so I need to enable the multidexing library (I work on `Android 4.4`).

Because of that, I just can't compile anymore, it's taking way too long. Without Robolectric and multidex, compiling takes maybe a minute, and I don't get anything after more than 30 minutes when including Robolectric and multidex.

Here is my complete gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cm.smobilpay.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled true
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        unitTest // Creates a new scope which wraps only unit tests
    }

    sourceSets {
        unitTest {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/test/java' // New scope includes our unit test folder
            }
        }
    }

    // Prevent conflicts between Robolectric's dependencies
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        xmlReport true
    }

}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'s3papiandroidclient', ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


    // Unit testing dependencies
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit-dep', version: '4.10'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'

    unitTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
}
```

**My question is** : what am I doing wrong that makes me being forced to use multidex when including Robolectric to my project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robolectric should not be included in your dex at all. Robolectric tests run on the JVM, they do not get deployed on devices.

You should be including it with `testCompile` as described in [the docs](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/).

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
```

Comment: I'm amazed about how easy it was to fix that... I was following a guide to have a complete integration of my Android project with Robolectric and Jenkins, and it looks like the unitTest flavor was the thing that was messing everything up. I completely removed it, removed dexing as well, and now it works fine for both testing and compiling. Kudos !

Comment: No worries. Might be an older guide, gradle support for robolectric wasn't always this straightforward.